# How can find out where a system message originates ("testing the buffer" in dmesg / journalctl / messages)?

Tags: systemd-journald, journalctl

In the past few days I have had a message in the system log/journal over a thousand times within a second.  How can I find out where it originated?

```
# journalctl --system | grep "testing the buffer" | uniq --count
1522 Apr 06 13:49:31 laptop unknown: testing the buffer
```

So, 1522 times the same message by "unknown".  Is this possibly malicious?

```
# find / -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "testing the buffer" | grep -v /var/log/journal
Exit 1
```

No system file contains that string!

The system uses `systemd-journald` for system logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be related to latest kernel (5.6.x).

If you tail the journal with verbose level

```
sudo journalctl -f -o verbose
```

You can see _TRANSPORT=kernel

```
Sun 2020-04-12 09:32:38.852081 CEST [s=ca0e47a50a2047e483013075418f4a72;i=1d58f89;b=343f4563d34649baad6f57aacc0320a1;m=e9cad4480;t=5a312f895b1f1;x=16d4d0c3d713857c]
    _MACHINE_ID=*******
    _HOSTNAME=*******
    _TRANSPORT=kernel
    PRIORITY=4
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=1
    MESSAGE=testing the buffer
    _BOOT_ID=343f4563d34649baad6f57aacc0320a1
    _SOURCE_MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP=62758810437
```

There is a bug indeed listed for OpenSUSE https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1168664 (but kernel related, I'm on Ubuntu) fixed as minot leftover at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=41c55ea6c2a7ca4c663eeec05bdf54f4e2419699

Fortunately nothing to worry, it will disappear when they merge the fix into packaged kernel...

Answer (score 2):

1. The string "testing the buffer" sits inside of kernel 5.6.5 file `./net/bpfilter/main.c`
2. I expect that this harmless DEBUG message will disappear in future kernel releases.
3. I found the source of this message as follows:

   1. In a bash shell entering the root of kernel 5.6.5 source tree
   2. Executing:

      ```
      for i in find . -name "*.c"
      do 
      echo $i 
      grep "testing the buffer" $i 
      done > pq.log
      ```
   3. Inside of file pq.log locating the string per opening and inspecting the file with

      ```
      vi pq.log
      ```